# How to go up a directory with ajaxpages?

Tags: php, html, ajax

The problem I got, is that I can't go up a directory to open an ajaxpage.
Here is the link to the directory above:

```
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('pages/community.php', 'center');"><img src="../images/buttons/community.png" alt="Community" /></a>
```

This won't work. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript paths are relative to the page being displayed. Assuming you're viewing a page in the `pages` directory, you're actually requesting `pages/pages/community.php`.

Use `community.php` as your URL or use an absolute path.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this does not help. I am not viewing a page in the pages directory. And I can't use an absolute path, because then it won't open the community.php page inside the page I got the ajaxpage link.